# Run a macro from grunt in PhpStorm/WebStorm?

Tags: macros, automation, gruntjs, phpstorm, webstorm

I'd like to run recorded PhpStorm/Webstorm macros via grunt to perform post-build tasks in the IDE. Is there a way to do this and/or run macros from the command-line?

Comment: That is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea :

1. assign a shortcut on your saved macro PHPStorm
2. find a way to switch focus on your OS by command (not shortcut)
3. find a way to launch shortcut keyboard programmatically
4. create a script that can process the 1, 2 and 3 point process
5. find a way to launch this script into the grunt

I don't know grunt and depends on the OS you are but perhaps idea for resolve your problem.